# Disposal of AsyncLazy, what is the right (easy to use and non-leaky) way?

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm using a specialization of [Stephen Cleary's AsyncLazy implementation, from his blog.](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/asynchronous-lazy-initialization.html)

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides support for asynchronous lazy initialization.
/// This type is fully thread-safe.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">
/// The type of object that is being asynchronously initialized.
/// </typeparam>
public sealed class AsyncLazy<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The underlying lazy task.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Lazy<Task<T>> instance;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the 
    /// <see cref="AsyncLazy&lt;T&gt;"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="factory">
    /// The delegate that is invoked on a background thread to produce
    /// the value when it is needed.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="start">
    /// If <c>true</c> commence initialization immediately.
    /// </param>
    public AsyncLazy(Func<T> factory, bool start = false)
    {
        this.instance = new Lazy<Task<T>>(() => Task.Run(factory));
        if (start)
        {
            this.Start();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the 
    /// <see cref="AsyncLazy&lt;T&gt;"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="factory">
    /// The asynchronous delegate that is invoked on a background 
    /// thread to produce the value when it is needed.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="start">
    /// If <c>true</c> commence initialization immediately.
    /// </param>
    public AsyncLazy(Func<Task<T>> factory, bool start = false)
    {
        this.instance = new Lazy<Task<T>>(() => Task.Run(factory));
        if (start)
        {
            this.Start();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Asynchronous infrastructure support.
    /// This method permits instances of
    /// <see cref="AsyncLazy&lt;T&gt;"/> to be await'ed.
    /// </summary>
    public TaskAwaiter<T> GetAwaiter()
    {
        return this.instance.Value.GetAwaiter();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Starts the asynchronous initialization, 
    ///     if it has not already started.
    /// </summary>
    public void Start()
    {
        var unused = this.instance.Value;
    }
}
```

This is great code and I really appreciate how easy it is to use. i.e.

```
class SomeClass
{
    private readonly AsyncLazy<Thing> theThing = new AsyncLazy<Thing>(
        () => new Thing());

    void SomeMethod()
    {
        var thing = await theThing;
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Now my question,**

Suppose that `SomeClass` inherits from a class that implements `IDisposable` and that `Thing` implements `IDisposable`. We'd have skeleton implementation like this,

```
class SomeClass : SomeDisposableBase
{
    private readonly AsyncLazy<Thing> theThing = new AsyncLazy<Thing>(
        () => new Thing());

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            // What do I do with theThing?
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

So, what do I do with `theThing` in the `Dispose` override? Should I extend `AsyncLazy<T>` to have a new property?

```
// ...

public bool IsStarted
{
    get
    {
        return this.instance.IsValueCreated;
    }
}

// ...
```

Should I change `AsyncLazy<T>` to implement `IDisposable`?

Have I misunderstood and I don't need to worry?

Should I do something else?

Comment: If it were me, I'd go for the last option... extend `AsyncLazy` such to implement `IDisposable`, then if `someT as IDisposable` is non-null, dispose it.

Comment: @spender, I'm tempted but then I consider, `T` will not always implement `IDisposable` so, its kind of a waste. Additionally, `Lazy<T>` doesn't implement `IDisposable` so I'd be breaking the pattern, as it were.

Comment: @spender, of course, doing all the checking, waiting and disposing for every instance is a pain.

Comment: There is a builtin `AsyncLazy` in Assembly `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading` look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn268899.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

[Stephen Toub's version of this class](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/15/10116210.aspx) inherits from `Lazy<Task<T>>`, so you get the `IsValueCreated` property automatically.

Alternatively, you could expose the `IsValueCreated` property from the private field:

```
public sealed class AsyncLazy<T>
{
    private readonly Lazy<Task<T>> instance;
    ...
    public bool IsValueCreated
    {
        get { return instance.IsValueCreated; }
    }
}
```

For consistency with the built-in `Lazy<T>` type, I'd avoid renaming the property to `IsStarted`.

Comment: This is what I'll probably do but, I think its semantically correct to expose the property as `IsStarted` since, creation of the task does not necessarily men that the value is instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `bool` inside the `AsyncLazy<T>` initialization to know if `theThing` has been initialized

```
class SomeClass : SomeDisposableBase
{
   public SomeClass()
   {
      theThing = new AsyncLazy<Thing>(() => 
      { 
         _isInitialized = true;
         return new Thing();
      } 
   }

   private bool _isInitialized;
   private readonly AsyncLazy<Thing> theThing;

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing && _isInitialized)
    {
        // Dispose Thing
    }

    base.Dispose(disposing);
 }
}
```

Although, if this pattern occurs in your code more than once, then i would definitely extend `AsyncLazy`

Comment: my `AsyncLazy<T>` doesn't have a `IsValueCreated` yet.

Comment: I thought stephans implementation was inheriting `IsValueCreated`. You can use a simple `bool` instead. Ill fix my code.

Comment: Which Stephen? Toub yes, Cleary no.

Comment: I modified the code to work with the version you posted, from stephan cleary. Too many stephans doing the same thing :)

Comment: That lambda syntax is interesting, though it's certainly not C#.

Comment: @svick Yah, the code changed a bit and i forgot to re-edit it. Fixed